# Parabola-like function $f$ such that $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $f(k)=1$ at a specified value of $k$

Tags: functions, conic-sections

I am looking for an equation form that will give me curves as shown below:

[image]

The function should take values of X between 0 and 1, and a shape parameter k with values between 0 and 1, to then yield curves of the form as shown above. Y values should be between 0 and 1 for all values of X and k.

So basically it is like a parabola but with the X value at which the maximum occurs shifting depending on the value of k. I am not too concerned about the slope of the curve towards the endpoints at x = 0 and x = 1.

Any suggestions much appreciated

Comment: Do you absolutely need a function $y=f(x)$? With a [quadratic a Bézier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézier_curve) it would be easy.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca - yes I need to implement the equation in a spreadsheet so it should be a relatively simple explicitly defined equation. Thanks for your interest in my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is the
Beta distribution
$B(x; a, b)
=x^a(1-x)^b
$
with appropriate normalization.

Since

$\begin{array}\\
B'(x; a, b)
&=ax^{a-1}(1-x)^b-x^a(1-x)^{b-1}\\
&=x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}(a(1-x)-bx)\\
&=x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}(a-(a+b)x)\\
\end{array}
$

$B(x; a, b)$
has an extreme value at
$x_{a, b}=\dfrac{a}{a+b}$
of

$\begin{array}\\
B_{a, b}
&=B(x_{a, b}; a, b)\\
&=x_{a, b}^a(1-x_{a, b})^b\\
&=(\dfrac{a}{a+b})^a(1-(\dfrac{a}{a+b}))^b\\
&=(\dfrac{a}{a+b})^a(\dfrac{b}{a+b})^b\\
&=\dfrac{a^ab^b}{(a+b)^{a+b}}\\
\end{array}
$

Note that
$x_{a, b}=1-x_{b, a}$.

To make the scaled
$B(k; a, b)=1$,
you want the scaling factor
$c(k)$
to satisfy
$c(k)B(k; a, b)
=c(k)k^a(1-k)^b
=1$
so the function is
$\dfrac{x^a(1-x)^b}{k^a(1-k)^b}
$.

Comment: Many thanks @marty cohen for your answer. It seems like this could work for me but I still need to get to grips with the influence of a,b and k in combination for various values of x. It seems that the value of k needed to constrain the function to 1 varies with a and b, which is not ideal for what I need. But I will play around with this and see what else comes up. If nothing else, I will mark your answer as the solution. Thanks again!